# Ionic 5: How to write to local JSON files?

Tags: json, angular, ionic-framework, ionic5

I'm developing an Ionic-Angular mobile application that involves tracking user progress. While I'm familiar with how to read from locally defined JSON files (and render that data), I've been unable to find any solutions online to write/append to local JSON files.

Until I'm able to utilize something like Google Firebase, I'd like to be able to just store this data by writing to local JSON.

Is there any way I can do this or is a database the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming this is a web application. There is no way you can access the file system of the user to persist the data.
Other options

1. [Index DB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) (save the information locally to the user at the browser level). User can go to the mobile device settings and clear it if required.
2. Use a mock api if this is only during the local development purpose (Use [json-server](https://medium.com/codingthesmartway-com-blog/create-a-rest-api-with-json-server-36da8680136d) and watch the `database json` file. You can update the `database json file` and it will reflect)
3. If you are building a hybrid application using ionic, then use one of the cordova plugins available [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/file).
4. Use an actual backend service which persists it in the database.

Comment: The Ionic app is meant to be downloaded on the user's device. So yes, it is a hybrid, cross-platform mobile app. I wasn't anywhere there were Capacitor/Cordova plug-ins for this, but I'll look into it.

Comment: Even if it’s a hybrid app you can still make use of the Storage options from Ionic and they takes care of your need.